# MSSQL - Get primary key of Group by MAX date of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With out using SQL Windows Functions, CLR or CTEs, how would I do something like this?

Consider this Dataset:

```
Dispatch_Id (PK)    | Job_Id    | Tech  | Scheduled_Time
    1               |   1       | Brad  |   08:35
    2               |   1       | John  |   05:29
    3               |   2       | Steve |   13:02
    4               |   3       | Brad  |   10:15
    5               |   3       | Kevin |   10:15
    6               |   4       | Kevin |   12:00
```

This is what I need to end up with:

```
Dispatch_Id (PK)    | Job_Id    | Tech  | Scheduled_Time
    2               |   1       | John  |   05:29
    3               |   2       | Steve |   13:02
    4               |   3       | Brad  |   10:15
    6               |   4       | Kevin |   12:00
```

This is the code i have started but the problem is that it is not getting the MIN(Dispatch_Id) for the MIN(Scheduled_Time).  I need them to work together.

```
SELECT   Job.Name
        ,NextAppt.Next_Appointment
        ,Tech.Tech_Name
FROM Job
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT Job_Id, MIN(Schedule_Time) AS Next_Appointment, MIN(Dispatch_Id) AS Dispatch_Id
            FROM Dispatch
            GROUP BY Job_Id) NextAppt ON Job.Job_Id = NextAppt.Job_Id
  LEFT JOIN Dispatch ON NextAppt.Dispatch_Id = Dispatch.Dispatch_Id
   LEFT JOIN Tech ON Dispatch.Tech_Id = Tech.Tech_Id
```

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

This is what i have done in the past but it gives me headaches and is slow in large queries.  Plus this does an alpha numeric sort on the dispatch id.  So it is not as precise when there are two of the same dates.

```
SELECT   Job.Name
        ,CAST(SUBSTRING(NextAppt.Next_Appointment,1,22) AS DATETIME) AS 'Next_Appointment'
        ,Tech.Tech_Name
FROM Job
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT Job_Id, MIN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25),Schedule_Time,126)+'-'+CAST(Dispatch_Id AS NVARCHAR)) AS Next_Appointment
            FROM Dispatch
            GROUP BY Job_Id) NextAppt ON Job.Job_Id = NextAppt.Job_Id
  LEFT JOIN Dispatch ON CAST(SUBSTRING(NextAppt.Next_Appointment,21,99) AS INT) = Dispatch.Dispatch_Id
   LEFT JOIN Tech ON Dispatch.Tech_Id = Tech.Tech_Id
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your sample query is just getting the min values for both Schedule_Time and Dispatch_ID for a single job.  What you should be doing is grouping by both job_id and dispatch_id, and then get the Top 1 of that ordered by time.  Or get the min time first, then a second join query to get the dispatch id for that job+time combo.

Comment: I don't want to group by the dispatch id because then i get a Cartesian product on the overall query.  The top is probably the key but i have to get the syntax correct.

Comment: SELECT  Job.Name
  ,CAST(SUBSTRING(NextAppt.Next_Appointment,1,22) AS DATETIME) AS 'Next_Appointment'
  ,Tech.Tech_Name
FROM Job
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT Job_Id, MIN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25),Schedule_Time,126)+'-'+CAST(Dispatch_Id AS NVARCHAR)) AS Next_Appointment
   FROM OE_Job_Dispatch
   GROUP BY Job_Id) NextAppt ON Job.Job_Id = NextAppt.Job_Id
  LEFT JOIN Dispatch ON CAST(SUBSTRING(NextAppt.Next_Appointment,21,99) AS INT) = Dispatch.Dispatch_Id
   LEFT JOIN Tech ON Dispatch.Tech_Id = Tech.Tech_Id

Comment: That is what i have done in the past but its usually gives me a lot of headache and is slow.

Comment: Plus this does an alpha numeric sort on the dispatch id.  So it is not as precise when there are two of the same dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method I was looking for.  It is very optimized assuming you are joining on the PK index.

```
SELECT   Job.Name
        ,NextAppt.Next_Appointment
        ,Tech.Tech_Name
FROM Job
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Job_Id, Dispatch_Id, Tech_Id, Schedule_Time AS 'Next_Appointment'
              FROM OE_Job_Dispatch
              WHERE Job_Id = Job.Job_Id
              ORDER BY Scheduled_Time) NextAppt
  LEFT JOIN Tech ON NextAppt.Tech_Id = Tech.Tech_Id
```

This method seems to use a Table Seek vs a slower Table Scan in the LEFT JOIN method.  This is the OUTER APPLY method:

[image]

This is the LEFT JOIN Method:

[image]

This is my previous Concatenation JOIN Method:
Remember this can be unpredictable if the data is not just right.  In this case it preforms fine but can be unreliable.

[image]

Comment: Just for reference.  When i tested and INNER JOIN vs CROSS APPLY in this case there was not a performance advantage between the two.  They both returned results in under a second.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but your derived table instead needs to use TOP 1 and ORDER BY instead of MIN.   It also needs to correlate on the `Job_Id`, but  JOIN ON the PK.

Example (I know I have posted this before, but I couldn't find it easily enough):

pseudocode because you've only posted query results and not DDL:

```
SELECT...
FROM SomeTables t1
INNER JOIN Dispatch t2 ON t2.PK=(
  SELECT TOP 1 PK
  FROM Dispatch t3
  WHERE t1.Job_id=t3.Job_id
  ORDER BY Schedule_Time, Dispatch_Id ASC
)
```

The resulting `t2` will have the first dispatch row for each `Job_Id` in `t1`.

Comment: The order by does not work in a sub query I thought?

Comment: It does if used in conjunction with TOP. @BKSwindell

Comment: I have seen one other method out there to do something like this and i just cannot figure out where i saw it.  it was using a different type of join like cross apply or something.  I just wish i archived it.  I have posted my work around above but i'm sure there is a much more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: I will give that a shot.  I have also found the other method.  I will post below as well.  It uses an "Outer Apply" and the TOP 1 / Order By method you described.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you can use Outer Apply, why can't you use windows functions?

Comment: Ill admin that i don't understand window functions enough to troubleshoot them.  However anytime i have tried to use them for this type of situation it has been a performance issue.  The query times slow down significantly.

Comment: So i just tested this method and it took 33 seconds to return 10195 results.  In comparison the Outer Apply method returned the same results in under a second.  It appears the Inner Join method is requesting an additional index for scanning the table.  Whereas the Outer Apply method avoids the table scan.

Comment: Interestingly enough i just checked and the query performance of an INNER JOIN and CROSS APPLY was about the same.  The problem is that i need the equivalent of a LEFT JOIN for the query.  And apparently in this case the OUTER APPLY preforms much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `TIES` clause :

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES d.*
FROM dataset d
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Job_Id ORDER BY Scheduled_Time, Dispatch_Id);
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() is a windows function.